# Django - User Uploaded CSV and JQueryCSVtoTable

Tags: python, django, csv, django-templates

I have a small django app that requires users to upload a csv file. I would like to access the file itself and use it with [jquerycsvtotable](https://code.google.com/p/jquerycsvtotable/).

I have successfully uploaded the file. How do I bring it into the template in a way the library can access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have something like a CSVFile model object, you'll want to pass that object to your template and access the file field's url property. Something like this:

Assuming something like this in your models.py:

```
class CSVFile(models.Model):
    ...
    file = models.FileField(...)
```

You'll need to lookup the object and pass it to your template in views.py:

```
def some_view(request, ...):
    ...
    obj = CSVFile.objects.get(...)
    return render('path/to/template.html', {'obj': obj})
```

And then get the url in template.html like so:

```
...
<div id="CSVTable"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('#CSVTable').CSVToTable({{ obj.file.url }});
});
</script>
...
```

See the documentation on [Django FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield) for more information.